# How to set a condition before assigning value to a property in html and angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

```
<div #dataContainer class="infills richtextbox {{field.groupid}}"
                    contentEditable="true" 
                    *ngIf="field.fieldtype=='text'"
                    id="{{field.id}}" 
                    name="{{field.id}}" 
                    [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute','top':field.y+'px','left':field.x+'px','font-size': field.fontsize,'font-family':field.fontfamily,'width':field.width+'px','height':field.height+'px','border':'1px solid #FFF','background':'#EEE','overflow':'hidden' }"
                    title="{{field.description}}"
                    [(ngModel)]="field.value" 
                    (keypress)="_keyPress($event,field.pattern)"
                    (dblclick)="openFullRTE(field.id)" 
                    (focusout)="field.htmlContent=dataContainer.innerHTML;">
</div>
```

Here, I want to see if **field.description** has value "desc" and if so assign the value as empty to **title** attribute or else it can contain the value in field.description. How can I achieve this? Can it be possible using ternary operator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ternary operator or even call out to a function.  First you'll need to wrap the `title` attribute in brackets.  It'll look something like this:

```
[title]="field.description == 'desc' ? 'some value' : ''"
```

Or call out to a function that returns the appropriate value:

```
[title]="getFieldDescription(field.description)"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked.What I was missing was to wrap the title in brackets. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very useful, for examle when you want to set value to a property only if it's not null: [max]="endDate !== null ? endDate: nowDate" (it's from Angular's datepicker :)